How much drywall to remove?
My finished basement flooded a few days ago. In places, the water was an inch deep. It's all been professionally pumped out. We've ripped out the carpet and baseboards, and fans are still drying out what's left. I will remove drywall because it has swollen and to spray the plates and hidden areas with mildew prevention. I'll also replace at least the bottom foot of insulation.
The question is: how much drywall I should remove? Is it worthwhile to save as much as I can? My first thought is to remove the lower two feet. One advantage is that I can get two lengths of drywall from every new sheet. Two feet should also be enough space to completely feather out the joint compound above the new baseboard.
Is this a good plan? I'm open to any suggestions.
[Please ignore the part of my profile that says I live in Kazakhstan. My problem is in Utah.]

Do you know how high the moisture got in the insulation?

@Huesmann I do not know yet. I should investigate that.

It's good you caught the flood so quickly. Unfortunately, this question cannot be answered in a quality manner until you know at least 3 more important data points: (1) What is the highest height visibly affected by the moisture? Note that water will often creep up the back side (hidden) of drywall more than the front (visible) side. (2) Has it ever flooded before (or any area above it)? (3) Was your current drywall up to code for the use of the room and the equipment in the basement?

@Amazon Dies In Darkness I am not physically in the US now, so I must rely on my wife to get help opening up the wall. (I don't want her to accidentally slice through Romex with a keyhole saw, and she is too frightened of utility knives to get in there ASAP.) I should know by the end of Monday how high the water went. The whole basement has never flooded before. The sewer did back up into the bathroom 2-3 times, but I always got the water vacuumed up before it could do much damage. The drywall was normal for living spaces in 1995, when I hung it.

I think 2ft is a good plan. You can split the 4x8 in half and save some money. Taking it back 4ft, even if perfectly cut, would still result in a butt joint and may not be as clean with existing tape in that joint.

Agreed. If I was doing this i would cut it at 2 feet. That width gives a good strength to the new piece.

But it really depends how high the water wicked into the insulation.

You have two main considerations:

The height of the moisture damage
The integrity of replacement sheets due to size

Only remove as much as you need to in order to clear the damage. The exception would be if the damage is limited to a very low height, I wouldn't use strips smaller than about 12" for strength reasons. Even at a 12" repair height your joint won't be a problem with respect to the baseboard trim.
